# How to find out the biggest memory leaks?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

For my iOS app tuning with instruments of xcode4,

> - Using activity monitor

Real memory usage increase from 10+ MB to 100+ MB 
(I use iPod for testing, doubt that my app can use memory to 100+ MB, impossible ? )

> - Using memory leaks

Sort up with bytes, the biggest memory blocks seem only 100 KB, seem like non-sense

Any good practice to find out the biggest memory leaking ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it shows you 100MB+ then you probably use that much - this is what a memory leak can cause: because of not freeing allocated memory, even if memory blocks a small per se, it can cumulate to big numbers. And a lot of 100Kb blocks can sum up to a lot of memory, if you create lots of them.

So look not only on the biggest memory block but above all for the number of memory blocks or generally number of living objects. Make heap snapshots and compare them - after warming up you applications (warming means filling caches and variables) you should not see an increase in number of living objects any more.